# Prove $x=a+b\sin{x}$ have one solution for all choosing $a\in\mathbb{R}, b\in(0,1)$

Tags: calculus

Prove $x=a+b\sin{x}$ have **one** solution for all choosing $a\in\mathbb{R}, b\in(0,1)$

**My Attempt**:

We can see that $\sin{x}$ is continuous function in $[-1,1]$ and derative in $(-1,1)$.

let assume for this equation has two solution $x_1,x_2$, take a look in $[x_1,x_2]$,

$x=a+b\sin{x}$, $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$ the function is continuous

by Rolle's theorem exists $x_0$ in the part such that $x_1<x_0<x_2$, $f'(x_0)=0$, however $f'(x_0)=b\cos{x}-1$

unfortunately, I couldn't finish this prove I was stuck here.

Comment: Hint : Analyze the derivate of $f(x)=x-b\sin(x)$ , if $0<b<1$ to show the uniqueness and use the intermediate value theorem for the existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x-a-b\sin(x)$. This function is obviously continuous and differentiable everywhere. We have that $f'(x)=1-b\cos(x)>0$ since $$-1<\cos(x)<1\iff\\ -b<-b\cos(x)<b\iff\\ 1-b<1-b\cos(x)<1+b$$ So $f'(x)>0\quad ∀x∈\mathbb{R}$ which means that $f(x)$ is increasing. Now, $$\lim_{x\to-∞}f(x)=-\infty$$ and $$\lim_{x\to∞}f(x)=\infty$$. So there is a point and only one due to the monotony that the graph of $f$ crosses the $x$-axis, or else, there is a $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_0)=0$. I tried to give the answer with all the details in order to be easily understood.

Comment: Thanks, In the last sentence, do you use Rolle's theorem?

Comment: No my friend. I use the Bolzano Theorem. Because the limits are as above, there exist some $u<0$ and $v>0$ such that $f(u)<0$ and $f(v)>0$ so $f(u)•f(v)<0$ which implies that there exists some $w∈(u,v)$ s.t. $f(w)=0$.